# Problem in overlapping image using OpenCv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to just overlap a logo pic with some another picture but getting this:

`error on line 10 :  (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'`

The code snippet I am trying to run is as follows:

```
img2 = cv2.imread('Capture.jpg' , cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
logo = cv2.imread('pyt.jpg')

rows , cols , channel = img2.shape
roi = img2[0:rows , 0:cols]
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(logo , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret , mask = cv2.threshold(gray_img , 220 , 255 , cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#cv2.imshow('mask' , mask)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
#cv2.imshow('img' , mask_inv)

img_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi , roi , mask = mask_inv) #error on this line
#img_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(logo, logo , mask = mask)
#dst = cv2.add(img_bg , img_fg)
#logo[0:row , 0:col] = dst
#cv2.imshow('img' , img1)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that the mask should have the same size as the destination. The error in your code comes from this part:

```py
rows , cols , channel = img2.shape
roi = img2[0:rows , 0:cols]
```

`roi` is supposed to have the size of the logo, not the whole image!

Instead of using bitwise operations, it's much simpler to just copy the logo using the mask, of course, being careful with the ROI size:

```py
rows , cols = logo.shape[:2]
roi = img2[0:rows , 0:cols]

cv.copyTo(logo, mask, roi)
```